# Optimization of Circles inside a Rectangle

Tags: geometry, optimization

I'm trying to figure out the mathmatical explaination for placing the area of which a siren covers within a certain area. I'm working on a Math AA SL IA right now and I'm very stuck. I sense that there is an explaination for my work but I guess I'm not at that level yet. I have a rudimentary understanding of calculus, and I was thinking that my problem now has something to do with the optimization of circles in a rectangle.

I have 7 sirens that covers a 2 miles radius that I've placed in a city that has the dimensions of 10*5 miles. [The first diagram I made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvhZr.jpg) is based on the fact that all sirens are within the city limits and are equidistant from each other. I used the model where there are 7 circles within a rectangle that follow the shape of a flower almost (I can't remember the name of the arrangement), but I moved the top and bottom layer of the arrangment inside the rectangle so that all "sirens" (centers of the circles) are inside the city.

The [next diagram I made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96KvK.jpg) I just moved the circles around to create the least space possible in between them by eye-balling it... The area of the circles can overlap. Is there another way for me to explain my choices with this second diagram instead of saying I just "eye-balled" it?

Comment: Take a look at this [publication](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X99001304)

Comment: Could you explain a little what "Math AA SL IA" are ? These abbreviations are unknown in my country (France).

Comment: @JeanMarie Sorry about that, I'm an IB (International Baculaurette) student and I'm taking a Standard Level (SL) Math Analysis and Approaches (AA) class. I'm working on my Individual Assessment (IA) which is essentially a paper that I write about a topic that relates to my level of math- calculus is part of the cirriculum. I guess it's to engage myself in my course and it's a part of my final grade to pass my class and recieve a diploma. I've created this scenario for my IA